# change installed version of icedtea

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, java, jdk, jvm, openjdk

I've installed openJDK6 64-bit server on my ubuntu image running in a VM. I installed it here in order to do some testing in comparison with our production environment. however, our production environment is using

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.9) (6b20-1.9.9-0ubuntu1~10.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

while the version i've installed on my VM is:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

(note the different version of IcedTea)

How can I revert to the older version of iced tea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to a file called `preferences` in `/etc/apt` (create it if it isn't there)

```
Package: openjdk-6-jdk
Pin: version 1.9.9
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

The 1001 means that the older version takes priority over any newer version, and so the older version should be installed (and kept at this release even if you run `dist-upgrade`)

Comment: so how then do I actually change the version of iced tea? Re-run "sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk"?